# Where does SAS save log files when log is full?

Tags: sas, logfile

I forgot to printto my log and it filled up. I tried to choose the 'save' option from the popup window. I entered a name+path for the log and it didn't accept it. I tried entering just a name and it accepted it, but I have no idea where it saved to.

I've searched around and found many answers on how to avoid this situation, but no answers on where the save option puts your log.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is saved as a catalog entry in `SASUSER.PROFILE` with whatever name you gave it.  `FILE` is the way to get it saved as a text file rather than a catalog entry.

Note, this only works if you have write access to SASUSER; if you regularly run SAS with `rsasuser` or if you share user profiles for whatever reason (or if you're running a second+ copy of the same SAS session), the `save` option will not work at all (and should give you an error).

Answer (score 0):

You can also specify `-altlog="<path to log>"` on the SAS exe invocation/shortcut. This writes the entire session log to file as you go along.

Comment: While a good point, this doesn't address the question at all (which specifically mentions a lack of interest in things like this).